# MYSQL Sorting items in a group and then sorting them groups

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

What would be the best way to sort items in a group and then sort them, groups.

For example, we have:

**Fruit**

```
Apple
Pear
Peach
Melon
```

**Vegetables**

```
Asparagus
Beetroot
Broccoli
```

**Herbs**

```
Basil
Dill
Ginger
```

Let's imagine these all sit in the same table named 'Ingredients' with 3 fields

1. ID
2. Group
3. Item

How would this best be done, would the use of subqueries compromise optimisation?

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY group, item`.

Comment: Just fill in every record like this: `1-Fruit-Apple & 2-Fruit-Pear` etc. and when you call them with a query, use `ORDER BY Group, Item`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Looks like one of my really old exam questions...

Comment: They're columns, not fields, and I doubt any of them are called Group!!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Ingredients
ORDER BY group_name, item;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you do `GROUP BY group_name` there will just be one row for all the items in a group, you won't get each item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two order by's (just it)

```
SELECT      ID,
            GROUP,
            ITEM
FROM        YOURTABLE
ORDER BY    GROUP, ITEM
```